# Undefined method `average'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, raty

I'm trying to calculate the average star rating of a movie object in my rails app using raty.js. Here's a snippet of my code:

controllers/movies_controller.rb

```
def show
  @avg_review = @movie.average(:rating)
end

private
def set_movie
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "movies", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "description"
  t.integer  "image_id"
  t.string   "director"
  t.float    "rating"
  t.integer  "num_ratings"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.text     "url"
  t.string   "tracking"
end
```

I keep getting the error:

```
undefined method `average' for #<.Movie:0x5b385d0>
```

From my understanding, this is [a predefined method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/average) in rails. Yet, I'm getting the error. Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the docs you referenced, `average` is meant to be called on the `Movie` model itself, not an instance of it.

This will return the average of the column.

```
@avg_review = Movie.average(:rating)
```

You can also add conditions to the query (I made up a column for demonstration purposes):

```
# Get average of movie ratings from 2015
@avg_review = Movie.average(:rating).where(year: '2015')
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem for me :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`average`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/average) method documentation. it's a method for `ActiveRecord::Calculations` so you should use it on `ActiveRecord` collections or on the model directly, but you trying to use it on instance:

Wrong:

```
@avg_review = @movie.average(:rating)
```

Right:

```
@avg_review = Movie.average(:rating)
```